# How to put variable into cookie value

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I need to put the email var in the cookie value, can I? This method don't work with "$email", in the \php\Newsletter-signup.php there is the $email var

```
     <?php
  include '\php\Newsletter-signup.php';

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                function createCookie(key, value) {
                    let cookie = escape(key) + "=" + escape(value) + ";";
                    document.cookie = cookie;
                    console.log(cookie);
                    console.log("Creating new cookie with key: " + key + " value: " + value);
                }
                createCookie("Email", "$email");
            </script>'
?>
```

Comment: Yes you can, but you'd need to use single quotes for `$email` to be expanded. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php (Plus your line is missing a `;`)

Comment: @bromebeer how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do with this code (check howto interpolate a php variable inside a php string):

```
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     function createCookie(key, value) {
         let cookie = escape(key) + "=" + escape(value) + ";";
         document.cookie = cookie;
         console.log(cookie);
         console.log("Creating new cookie with key: " + key + " value: " + value);
     }
     createCookie("Email", "' . $email . '");
 </script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

`$email` will not be expanded since you are using single quotes in your `echo`. Either use single quotes (and adjust any single quote inside your string) or use

```
createCookie("Email", "' . $email . '");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: this work, it create the name of cookie etc but from google chrome in applications>cookies in the value column the email isn't displayed